# Gson will happily make JSON with List<Pair<String, String>> but not if the list is in a class

Tags: json, gson

As have many before me, I need to make a 'table' of key, value pairs.   There can be mulitples of either and I don't need to sort.  A List of Pairs seemed like a good choice but now I cannot get GSon to properly create JSON for the the class that holds them.

I could look for other ways, but now my curiosity is piqued.

It is no trouble to get JSON for a `List<Pair<String, String>>`

```
@Test
void listOfPairs() {
    List<Pair<String, String>> pairs = new ArrayList<>();

    pairs.add(new ImmutablePair<>("Test1", "Has Value1"));
    pairs.add(new ImmutablePair<>("Test1", "Has Value2"));
    pairs.add(new ImmutablePair<>("Test2", "Has Value2"));

    String json = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create().toJson(pairs);
    System.out.println(json);
}
```

Running this 'test' provides a nice lush JSON object :

```
[
   {
      "left": "Test1",
      "right": "Has Value1"
   },
   {
      "left": "Test1",
      "right": "Has Value2"
   },
   {
      "left": "Test2",
      "right": "Has Value2"
  }
]
```

But when the `List<Pair<String, String>>` is a member of a class, it is not so much.

```
class Thing {
    private List<Pair<String, String>> pairs = new ArrayList<>();
    private String thingName = "Benjamin Jacob Grimm";

    Thing() {
        pairs.add(new ImmutablePair<>("One", "1"));
        pairs.add(new MutablePair<>("Two", "1"));
        pairs.add(new ImmutablePair<>("Two", "2"));
    }
}

@Test
void thingTest() {
    Thing thing = new Thing();
    String json = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create().toJson(thing);
    System.out.println(json);
}
```

Now the response is entirely un-lush! :

```
{
  "pairs": [
       {},
       {},
       {}
  ],
  "thingName": "Benjamin Jacob Grimm"
}
```

Again, I could look for another storage mechanism, but I'm sure curious what is wrong here.    Anybody have any thoughts?

Comment: I think this is likely an issue with type erasure and Lists.  I even suspect someone smarter than me could explain why this is expected and proper.   I am hoping they will ;-)

Comment: Still hoping...

Answer (score 1):

Try to provide the `TypeToken` for `toJson`, Something like:

```
Type type = new TypeToken<Pair<String, String>>() {}.getType();

String json = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create().toJson(pairs, type);
System.out.println(json);
```

---

<sub>Didn't test it :)</sub>

Comment: Well.. I have seen that in other SO responses but my problem isn't with the `pairs` object itself.  Notice that the object JSON'd nicely in the first example.   The problem is when the `List<Pair<String, String>>` object is a member of a class.